# Define users and roles in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to define a user in MongoDB which able to read the all collection within the DB but able to insert data to only two collections: Logs and Metrics.

I used the next commands to set it:
Create a role:

```
use Emerald
db.runCommand({ createRole: "ApiReaderRole",
  privileges: [
    { resource: { db: "Emerald", collection: "Metrics" }, actions:  [ "insert" ] },
    { resource: { db: "Emerald", collection: "Logs" }, actions:  [ "insert" ] }
  ],
  roles: [
    { role: "read", db:"Emerald" }
  ],
  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
})
```

Create a user:

```
use Emerald

db.createUser({
    "user": "EmeraldAPIreader",
    "pwd": "emrldApi+",
    "roles": [
        {
            role: "ApiReaderRole",
            db: "Emerald"
        },
        {
            role: "read",
            db: "Emerald"
        }
    ]
},
{
    w: "majority",
    wtimeout: 5000
})
```

I add the required credentials to the connection string and when I'm trying to insert (through C# code) a data to collections which I defined as read only, it succeeds (I'm expecting to get an unauthorized exception).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is working fine for me on MongoDB 2.6. Can you show exactly the steps you used to log into the mongo shell, create the user (already there), log in as the EmeraldAPIreader, and do the unauthorized insert? Have you tried testing the permissions in the mongo shell vs. with the C# driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
I didn't run MongoDB service under [Auth - Client Access Control](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) mode.
Now, using Auth flag, everything works fine.